# How to do in app navigation using google assistant

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I have used actions for google and dialog flow agent to land the user in my app from google assistant. however, I'm wondering if there is a way to navigate from the landing view to a different fragment using the google assistant. for example, imagine Google assistant has landed the user on the search page of a shopping app, now I want to navigate him to cart by adding the product in the cart. So that would just be a click of add to cart button if the user were using the app normally.so, is there a way where I can trigger the click of that button using google assistant?

Answer (score 0):

According to this: [Use Google Assistant to directly talk to my Android app and execute a very simple task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479510/use-google-assistant-to-directly-talk-to-my-android-app-and-execute-a-very-simpl)

There is no current support for communications between an app and the google assistant.

Comment: ```If your GA is built upon Dialog flow API (specifically not using action-on-google), then you can use Dialog flow Android client in your Android App to communicate with Dialog flow Agent.``` This is part of the answer in the above-mentioned link. any idea how can this be done?

Comment: To my interpretation, that is saying you can use DialogFlow's API directly in your app. So in your app, you would have some sort of speech-to-text or chatbot UI and your app would send requests to DialogFlow directly without going through GA